# Constant values as array element gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, constants

I am new to `Typescript`.
I have these enum and constant variables:

```
enum VALUE_MAP = { value1 = 'value1', value2 = 'value2', value3 = 'value3' }
const SOME_CONSTANT = [VALUE_MAP.value1, VALUE_MAP.value2];
```

And a method which uses `SOME_CONSTANT` to check if value exists.

```
export const hasValue = (value: string) => SOME_CONSTANT.includes(value);
```

This gives me error:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'VALUE_MAP'.`

Using `(value: VALUE_MAP) =>` will solve the issue, but I don't want to do that or may be I want to know why `VALUE_MAP` is getting used as type

Any help?

Comment: i'd use an enum for this case.

Comment: to clarify if your object was like this `const VALUE_MAP = { value1: 'valueA', value2: 'valueB', value3: 'valueC' }` when calling hasValue you would pass `value1` or `valueA`?

Comment: It's inferring the type from the way you've declared `VALUE_MAP`.  I'm guessing that `const VALUE_MAP: any = {...}` would solve this in this case, but is a workaround.... enum is def the way to go per @DanielA.White comment.

Comment: @DanielA.White Forgot to mention but `VALUE_MAP` is enum.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for hint, Changing `VALUE_MAP` to const fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
export const hasValue = (value) => SOME_CONSTANT.includes(value);
```

Without `string` for param.
If you use Babel plugins, this will strip parameter types during transpiling.

Input:

```
function foo(one: string, two: number): string {}
```

Output:

```
function foo(one, two) {}
```

So, parameter types are not valid in ES6. You can use them if the code is transpiled using Babel(with the stripping plugins).

Comment: The question is tagged with `TypeScript`, so I would guess the TypeScript compiler is being used.

Comment: Removing string in `one: string` works. But if use `SOME_CONSTANT ` somewhere else, like in render method, it gives same error . Like `SOME_CONSTANT.includes(this.props.value)` gives error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target ES2016 or newer if you want to use `Array.includes` as it didn't exist in ECMAScript 5.

For example, this `tsconfig.json` fails with the error you describe:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5"
    }
}
```

And this `tsconfig.json` doesn't:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a working version in VSCode with this config. What tools are you using, and how are you compiling?

Answer (score 0):

After @Daniel A. White, pointed that I should be using `enum`. Then I got a little hint and changed a little bit of code.
So `VALUE_MAP` was already an `enum`. I changed it to `constant`, and it worked. Thanks everyone for you time and suggestion.

Not getting errors now.